# Finding files starting with variable given by users

Tags: c#

```
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*check*.*");
```

This returns me any files with name check. But what i want is return those file starting with string given by users.
Example

```
string word = Console.Readkey();
System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*word*.*");
```

I tried this

```
System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*"+word+"*".*");
```

But this didnt work

Comment: Try `dir.GetFiles("*" + word + "*.*");`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @ArghyaC Doesn't the OP say he wants files *starting* with the input?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Yes, he says so. But the example followed his own code which actually translates to *"files containing the user input in filename"*.

Comment: @ArghyaC So true.. `*word*.*`..

Comment: hmmm very stupid question i suppose. yes  dir.GetFiles("*" + word + "*.*") works fine. Should have studied my code before posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `Console.ReadKey()` reads a key which I think you don't intend it to do, so change it to `Console.ReadLine()`.

That being said, if you want to use the variable `word`, you don't put within the string. Put it outside and either concatenate with the rest of the pattern or use `String.Format()`.

So use this code:

```
string word = Console.ReadLine();
System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles(String.Format("{0}*.*", word));
```

Comment: Missed `*` at the start : `*{0}*.*`.

Comment: @DovydasSopa But OP says he wants filenames **starting with** the input. But putting a leading `*` will return files which **contain** the input somewhere in the middle.

Comment: oh ya, true. Missed that word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern
)
```

method from Directory class. The version with one string parameter accepts the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles(string.Format("{0}*.*", word));
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation and any relevant references in addition to the above code?